# GPUImage memory leaks when use filters

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, gpuimage

After the execution of the code, I have the memory usage increases. How can I free up memory after execution?

The problem is reproduced only when I save the image in the file system. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

My Code:

```
let contrastfilter = GPUImageContrastFilter()
    contrastfilter.contrast = 1.4

let thresholdImageFilter = GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter()
thresholdImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 16.0

let filterGroup = GPUImageFilterGroup()
filterGroup.addFilter(contrastfilter)
filterGroup.addFilter(thresholdImageFilter)
contrastfilter.addTarget(thresholdImageFilter)

filterGroup.initialFilters = [ contrastfilter ]
filterGroup.terminalFilter = thresholdImageFilter

let resultImage = filterGroup.image(byFilteringImage: image)
```

Comment: The memory should free itself as soon as your objects are not longer referenced. Did you try the Instruments-tool to check for memory-leaks?

Comment: May be it's some cache. After processing 5 photos my memory usage increase to 200 MB, and after this space not free. Then I got memory crash

Comment: Use the XCode Instruments, (command+i) and select "Leaks". Then run the app as you would when the crash occurs. The instruments-tool will show you on which line of code the memory-leak occurs.

Comment: I didn't find any leaks in gpuimage. I think this is some cache, that not clean after processing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place those parts of your code (`UIImage` declarations, Filter operations, etc.) which memory you need to release inside `autoreleasepool` block. It helps to manually reduce memory usage.

Comment: Thanks. I try it, no effect.

Comment: When I first faced such issue and tried to use `autoreleasepool` it had no effect too. I would suggest trying to change the place and area of this block. For instance, in my case the trick was to place it *inside* the loop statement (I was handling lots of images) and inside the block I had to place the assignment my image to the imageView statement. So maybe play a bit around it

Comment: I try to put `autoreleasepool` in processing block and in rx map. I think that the resources used by gpuimage not considered available for the system and `autoreleasepool` can't clear them. I told that it could be some gpuimage cache